# r - lapply divides a column by an integer value from different dataset, unexpected result

Tags: r, dataframe, division, lapply

I have two data.frames, one with genotype counts and one with a number that I need to normalize my counts from the first dataset.

```
countsdata=data.frame(genotype1=rep(c(10,20,30,40),each=1),
                       genotype2=rep(c(100,200,300,400),each=1),
                       genotype3=rep(c(40,50,60,70),each=1),
                       genotype4=rep(c(40,50,60,70),each=1)
                      )
coldata = data.frame(Group =c('genotype1', 'genotype2', 'genotype3', 'genotype4'),
                     Treatment = rep(c("control","treated"),each = 2),
                     Norm=rep(c(1,2,5,5)))
```

I made sure my variables don't have factors

```
factorsCharacter <- function(d) modifyList(d, lapply(d[, sapply(d, is.factor)],   
                                                     as.character))
coldata=factorsCharacter(coldata)
```

Then I see that lapply loops through my counts, one column at the time and through my coldata that contains the normalization value (Norm). All is looking good, until I combined the two action in the same step

```
> lapply(coldata['Group'],function(group_i){group_i})
$Group
[1] "genotype1" "genotype2" "genotype3" "genotype4"

> lapply(coldata['Group'],function(group_i){countsdata[,group_i]})
$Group
  genotype1 genotype2 genotype3 genotype4
1        10       100        40        40
2        20       200        50        50
3        30       300        60        60
4        40       400        70        70

> lapply(coldata['Group'],function(group_i){as.integer(coldata[coldata$Group==group_i,'Norm'])})
$Group
[1] 1 2 5 5

> lapply(coldata['Group'],function(group_i){
+ countsdata[,group_i]/as.integer(coldata[coldata$Group==group_i,'Norm'])
+ })
$Group
  genotype1 genotype2 genotype3 genotype4
1        10       100        40        40
2        10       100        25        25
3         6        60        12        12
4         8        80        14        14
```

Here the result is not what I was expecting (dividing each column by its normalization number). After further inspection I noticed it's normalizing by rows, in other words it's normalizing across different columns, which shouldn't be the case as I am looping through one column at the time. I am probably missing a basic concept but looking through other SO posts didn't find anything I could use. My goal is to fix the code to make the right calculation but I also would like to understand why this code above is not working. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using `[` and not `[[`.  So, instead of looping through each of the elements in 'Group' column, we have a `list` of length 1 with all the elements.  So, either use `coldata[, 'Group']` or `coldata[['Group']]` or `coldata$Group` for looping.

```
countsdataNew <- countsdata
countsdataNew[] <- lapply(coldata[['Group']],function(group_i)
                   countsdata[,group_i]/coldata$Norm[coldata$Group==group_i])
countsdataNew
#  genotype1 genotype2 genotype3 genotype4
#1        10        50         8         8
#2        20       100        10        10
#3        30       150        12        12
#4        40       200        14        14
```

---

If the column name in 'countsdata' and 'Group' column from 'countsdata' are in the same order, we can do this easily with `Map`

```
Map(`/`, countsdata, coldata$Norm)
```

Or just replicate the 'Norm' and do a simple division

```
countsdata/coldata$Norm[col(countsdata)]
```

Or with `sweep`

```
sweep(countsdata, 2, coldata$Norm, "/")
```

Comment: This is all super-useful. Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me a little more how does then the replication of Norm work here: `coldata$Norm[col(countsdata)]`, I checked the `col(countsdata)` and it's a 4*4 matrix, so I don't know if I understand the rules of replication.

Comment: @ecolog Here it is replicating by column index i.e. the `col(countsdata)` returns the column index replicated . i.e. 1st column in `col(countsdata)` have all 1, 2nd 2, 3rd 3  etc.  when we do `coldata$Norm[col(countsdata)]`, based on the index in col(countsdata), the elements in 'Norm' gets expanded or replicated. i.e. 1st element in 'Norm' would be replicated 4 times, followed by 2nd element 4 times and so on.  Instead of this, we can explicitly replicate Norm, i.e. `countsdata/rep(coldata$Norm, each = nrow(countsdata))`

Comment: Make sense,   Thanks!